# How to add text inside the box with plotly plot in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, box, rshiny

please look at the image with circled text. I used renderUI to show my plot but using that I couldn't add text like this picture. Can someone please help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/535z9.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your layout code:

```
layout( 
annotations = list(text = "Your text here :)",  x = 100, y = 25, showarrow=F),
...)
```